# A question about product of transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra

I came across this question below:

[Writing the identity permutation as a product of transpositions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560607/writing-the-identity-permutation-as-a-product-of-transpositions)

It's never elaborated how to write $(1)(2)(3)(4)$ as a $n \ge 3$ product of two-cycles if it's possible and how to further write it as a $n - 2$ product of cycles. Can you, please, elaborate on it a little.

Comment: For example: $e = (12)(12)(12)(12)$

Comment: @  Omnomnomnom, Does $(12)(12)(12)(12) = (1 2)$?

Comment: No, we have already $(12)(12)=e$, since the transposition $(12)$ has order $2$. Hence $(12)(12)(12)(12)=e\cdot e=e$. Of course, $(12)\neq e$.

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde, How do we compose $(12)(12)$? Let $f, g$ be bijective functions. Then, $f(1) = 2, g(2) = 1, f(2) = 1, g(1) = 2$. Then $(12)(12) = (21) = (12)$. Does that make sense?

Comment: No, that doesn't make any sense at all. The notation $(12)$ describes the function $f$ with $f(1)=2$ and $f(2)=1$. Composing twice, we get $f(f(1))=f(2)=1$ and $f(f(2))=f(1)=2$. So $f^2$ is the identity map. Swapping two things twice is the same as having not swapped them at all.

Comment: @user255751 that doesn't make sense.  If you want $f$ to be the bijection associated with $(12)$, then $f(1) = 2, f(2) = 1, f(3) = 3, f(4) = 4$.  We then find that $f \circ f$ is the identity map.

Comment: @ anon, Omnomnomnom, if $f^2 = (12)$, then $f^4 = (12)$. So, then $e = e(3)(4)$ because we can omit $1$-cycles. No?